# How to find $\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}$

Tags: functions, derivatives

How to find  $\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}$ in terms of $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$  for any implicit function which is twice differentiable  w.r.t.  both x and y.

I tried but we can't write  $\dfrac{d^2x}{dy^2}$ as $\dfrac{d(dx)}{d(dy)}$ separately ... can we?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you were asking for:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y}
&= \frac{1}{\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x}.
\end{align*}

So,

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}y^2}
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y} \frac{1}{(\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x)} \\
&= \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{1}{(\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x)} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x} \left( - \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y /\mathrm{d}x^2}{(\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x)^2} \right) \\
&= -\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y/\mathrm{d}x^2}{(\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x)^3}.
\end{align*}

Is this the relation that you wanted?

Comment: Hmm.. YES! (+1) it's what was needed . But can you use some `\dfrac` in your LaTeX to make it more appealing to eyes.....

Comment: Should learn how to use \dfrac. Will keep that in mind though

Comment: I had to tilt my head to read your answer :D

Comment: My bad ! Should learn the usage of \dfrac soon !:D

Comment: @learner I think even you din't get those two lines and so didn't added `\dfrac` there . lol